# React, NodeJS process data on frontend or backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql

I've the next case scenario:

[image]

Page that displays SQL exercises with the next functionalities:

The user can group them by:

- difficulty, category or random

The user can filter them by difficulty:

- easy, average, hard, very hard

From your experiences, for a number of 1000 records it's better to:

- Make a single request where I get all the exercises data from the backend and after that to process the data on front end?

OR

- Make multiple requests, and process data on backend

I tried both of them, I checked the loading times, and they were similars

What's would be your choice in this case?